# Why doesn't a reference to an array work until we use a pointer?

Tags: c++, reference

This works very well...

```
int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5}, int *p = a;
int *& ref = p;
```

But why doesn't this work?

```
int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int*& ref = a;
```

Both `a` and `p` are pointers and have the same value (address of `a[0]`).
When I make reference to an array using a pointer (`p`), it works very well.

But when I make reference to that array `a[]` directly, it doesn't work... Why?

Answer (score 25):

`a` is not a pointer, it is an array. It has the type `int[5]`. What it can do is decay to a pointer `int*`, which is what happens in the first case. So, taking a reference to `p` is ok.

Now for the second case. Remember that `a` is *not* a pointer. So, there is an implicit conversion happening from `int[5]` to `int*`. The result of that conversion is a prvalue. But you can't bind a non-const lvalue reference (which is what `ref` is) to an rvalue! So the code fails to compile.

Here's an analogy:

```
double a = 1.4;
int& b = a; // implicit conversion from 'double' to `int` results in prvalue
            // and you can't bind non-const lvalue refs to rvalues.
```

Answer (score 9):

Adding on to what has already been answered, you can get a reference to an array like

```
int a[5];
int (&ref)[5] = a;
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/g/vsCiBz)

Comment: I just was about to add this (but had to check for syntax errors before). Thus, I can at least add: `g++ -std=c++11` has accepted this. (But I remember that I also used it in VS2013 in the past.)

Comment: @Scheff This needs newer C++? Really? I thought this is ancient syntax. [Looks fine to me](https://godbolt.org/g/vsCiBz)

Comment: You are fully right. I simply described what I just have tested (not what I'm sure to know). (May be, my age has let me become overly carefully...)

Comment: Why don't you add the link with this nice demonstration to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
int*& ref = a;
```

`int*` is a pointer type, not an array type. So, that's why it won't bind to `a`, which has type `int[5]`.

So, use `const`

```
int* const& ref = a;
```

It's works fine, Because the array name is an address constant, non-const reference can not refer to a constant.

Comment: The array name is not an "address constant". This works because a const reference can be bound to the temporary that array decays produces.

Comment: Address of *static* array is an address constant. Address of *local* array is not.